# PayPal API Send Payments to Third Party Bank Accounts UK

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to use PayPal's API to send money direct to a third party's bank account, not a PayPal account? The business is located in the UK. We have looked at Stripe which is an excellent payment gateway, but they don't currently allow you to make payments direct to bank accounts outside of the US using their API.

Comment: No.  That's not how PayPal works.  Your UK third party could create a their own paypal account and accept money that way.  Then it would be in their PayPal account which they can then use to transfer the money down to their bank account.  https://www.paypal.com/uk/home

Comment: Thanks Greg. So if we are facilitating the payment and have the funds in our PayPal account, it isn't possible for us to transfer that using the API to a third party's bank account?

Answer (score -1):

Actually PayPal does seem to allow Direct Payment to USA and UK accounts.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments

In the UK Paypal calls it Website Payments Pro (UK) https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/pro

That seems to do what you want it to do.

Comment: That is not a direct to bank account transaction.  That is simply a credit card transaction where the money would fall into your PayPal account.